# Replacing backslash with forward slash in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace

I currently have a table with \paths\, but they need to be /paths/. Does anyone know what query I need to run in myPHPadmin to get it fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has replace function. [Here is the link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to mySQL docs.

```
update tablename set columnToUpdate = replace(columnToUpdate, '\\', '/');
```

Comment: That gives me an error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''bhl_product_image' set 'image' = replace('image', '\', '/')' at line 1

Comment: Try this query update tablename set columnToUpdate = replace(columnToUpdate, '\\', '/');

Comment: @Sokonomi Looks like you didn't double the backslash. And if you're running the query from PHP, you'll need to quadruple it.

Comment: @Sokonomi Don't put `bhl_product_image` or `image` in quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks